# JAVA classes and objects....what will be in my class

Tags: java, class, methods

For "this line" how will the code be? 
I know that for the "2nd part" setName,setWidth, setHeight....will be methods in the Box class...but im stuck on "this line" ...will it be 1 method?

```
    Box box1 = new Box(string, double , double); //this line

    //2nd part
    Box box2 = new Box(); //i get this part
    Box2.setName(String);
    box2.setWidth(double);
    box2.setHeight(double);
```

Comment: So you know that `box1` is an object. Let's figure out what the special method in OO languages to create new objects typically is called.

Comment: There might be multiple of these methods, each taking different arguments. Btw. you do know that this does not compile, right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a constructor and declare variables in class Box?

```
public class Box {

    private double height;
    private double width;
    private String name;

    // constructor for setting those variables
    public Box(double height, double width, String name) {

        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // constructor for creating object without setting variables
    public Box() {}
}
```

And then you can create an object like this:

```
Box box1 = new Box(20, 10.5, "MyName");
Box box2 = new Box();
```

Answer (score 0):

Box1 is created using a constructor and you are passing in parameters which are used to create the Name, Width and Height fields of the Box object.

With Box2 you are creating the object with the default constructor `Box box2 = new Box();`and then setting the fields of that object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a constructor to pass the parameters. I only did the custom constructor, to create your Box2 object you also need a blank constructor.

```
public class Box {
    public Box(String string, Double double1, Double double2) {
        //Set your variables
    }
    public Box() {
        //This is the standard constructor you use for Box2
    }

    //Specify your methods like setName(String s) etc.
}
```